# iOS8 / iPhone6+ XPC crash

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, iphone-6-plus

I have an app build on the iOS8 SDK which I archive and then sign for adhoc distribution.

This has been working for 2 years on all devices with various updates. Now I have an iPhone 6 plus.

The app ran fine the first after a new install but now it keeps crashing with error:

> "XPC API Misuse: Given object not of required type"

This happens before it gets into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Call stack:

`Thread 0 name:  XPC API Misuse: Given object not of required type.  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000197dd99d8 _xpc_api_misuse + 60
1   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000197dd99d4 _xpc_api_misuse + 56
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000197dc9ae8 xpc_dictionary_set_value + 88
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000197dc5538 xpc_dictionary_set_string + 48
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186e4b590 _CFXNotificationRemoveObservers + 912
5   Foundation                      0x0000000187d1ff20 -[NSNotificationCenter removeObserver:name:object:] + 252
6   UIKit                           0x000000018b8588e4 -[UITableView dealloc] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b6bf510 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 696
8   UIKit                           0x000000018b79cb24 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 76
9   UIKit                           0x000000018b6c219c -[UIView dealloc] + 444
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186e217e4 CFRelease + 520
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186e2dda4 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 148
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197599720 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 560
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186e25400 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
14  Foundation                      0x0000000187d1f180 -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 144
15  UIKit                           0x000000018b72f9ac -[UIApplication _run] + 584
16  UIKit                           0x000000018b72a980 UIApplicationMain + 1484
17  HelloWorld                      0x000000010000636c main (main.m:16)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000197beea04 start + 0`

Can anyone help?

Comment: I've had some scattered crash reports from users showing the same basic issue. All on the iPhone 6 and 6+. No other devices.

Comment: Same problem and only happens on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the crash in my own app but I can't 100% pin point the root cause. I suspect it was memory corruption or over retaining an object.

The key was `[UITableView dealloc]` I implemented dealloc in my table view to see where problem was occurring. I eventually traced it down to a `UITableViewCell` instantiated from a .xib file. This particular .xib contained multiple `UITableViewCell`s. After giving each table view it's own .xib the crash disappeared.

Comment: Have this issue, but use storyboard. Do you have any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: Same issue. It's one of our top crashes in our apps.

Comment: Seeing as you've got an "API Misuse" error, Apple regularly document on this throughout their XPC docs etc... Interstly enough it comes up in the man pages too. XPC has an pretty complex cache system that gels closely with `launchd` do just arbitrarily "re-running" a crashing app after making changes won't always fix it. XPC caches need flushing when it comes to XPC crashes. At times, it comes down to just waiting for launchd (in favour of causing utter maybe and stressing out)... Out of interest, the XPC cache flush is performed by `/usr/libexec/xpchelper --rebuild-cache`

Comment: PELASE TREAT THAT WITH WITH CARE, as XPC services run int eh background and rely on caching... This is purely for development use on a dev machine.

Answer (score 1):

for me, I got xpc api Misuse crash when I ran some video editing code from the simulator!(iOS 13), the problem doesn't appear on real device.